# How to set condition in MySQL query when filtering value is 0?

Tags: mysql, go

I'm writing a program in Go that needs to filter refund records in a database. My business requirement is that when the q.RefundStatus filtering condition is 0, I want this condition to be included in the query. My current code looks like this:

```
if q.RefundStatus != nil {
    repos.Condition.RefundStatus = *q.RefundStatus
}
```

I've noticed that when the value of q.RefundStatus is 0, this code does not add the condition to the query. However, when the value of q.RefundStatus is non-zero, the condition is added to the query as expected. So, I need help resolving this issue.

How can I modify the code to meet the following requirements:

When the value of q.RefundStatus is 0, include the condition in the query.

I have tried other approaches, such as checking for *q.RefundStatus != 0 in the conditional statement, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I hope someone can provide an effective solution. Thank you!

Comment: What library are you using to query the database? Is might see the zero as the default/empty value and omits it. Would you please produce a minimal reproducible example? It would help in figuring out what is causing the issue.